# Why LinkedTreeMap is generated after deserializing to another class using Gson?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I have JSON structure like following:

```
{
"status": 0,
"error_message": null,
"data": {
"1": {
  "7": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "person_id": "3",
      "friend_id": "2"
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

As you've noticed, the number of indexes(1, 7) are dynamic, I mean, they can be more. So, to parse this JSON, I decided to use `Map`. `7` can be used as a key, when `id, person_id, friend_id` can be a class named, for example, `Model`. So, firstly, I tried to get `1` from `data` in JSON and convert it to `Map` as I described above. Here is how I did it:

```
    val data = myJson.getAsJsonObject("data").get("1")
    val gson = Gson()
    val type = object : TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<Model>>>() {

    }.type
    val myMap: Map<String, ArrayList<Model>> = gson.fromJson(data, type)
```

Everything was alright, until I referred to some field of my `Model`. Here is how I did it:

First of all I tried to refer to `myMap` as following:

[image]

As you see, instead of getting `Model`, there are list of `LinkedTreeMap`. So, when I refer to the field of `Model`, I got `CastException`.

[image]

So, how to solve this problem? I tried this not using `TypeToken`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

you gave the wrong json one single closure "}" I think you've copied wrong

create Gson2Application class

```
class Gson2Application

val jj = "{\n" +
        "\"status\": 0,\n" +
        "\"error_message\": null,\n" +
        "\"data\": {\n" +
        "\"1\": {\n" +
        "  \"7\": [\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
        "      \"person_id\": \"3\",\n" +
        "      \"friend_id\": \"2\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  ]\n" +
        " }\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "}"

data class Model(val id: Long, val person_id: Long, val friend_id: Long)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var myJson = JsonParser().parse(jj).asJsonObject
    val data = myJson.getAsJsonObject("data").get("1")

    val type = object : TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<Model>>>() {}.type  // the Map is interfacem then gson get default LinkedTreeMap extedn AbstractMap<K,V> implements Map
    val fromMapDefault = Gson().fromJson<Map<String, List<Model>>>(data, type)

    printResult(fromMapDefault)
//    result
//        {{7=[Model(id=1, person_id=3, friend_id=2)]} class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap--> 1}
//        {[Model(id=1, person_id=3, friend_id=2)] class java.util.ArrayList--> 1}
//        {Model(id=1, person_id=3, friend_id=2)  class pl.jac.gson2.Model --> 2}
//        {1 long--> 3}

    val typeHashMap = object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Model>>>() {}.type // the HashMap is an implementation
    val fromHashMap = Gson().fromJson<Map<String, List<Model>>>(data, typeHashMap)
    printResult(fromHashMap)
//result
//    {{7=[Model(id=1, person_id=3, friend_id=2)]} class java.util.HashMap--> 1}
//    {[Model(id=1, person_id=3, friend_id=2)] class java.util.ArrayList--> 1}
//    {Model(id=1, person_id=3, friend_id=2)  class pl.jac.gson2.Model --> 2}
//    {1 long--> 3}

}

private fun printResult(fromMapDefault: Map<String, List<Model>>) {
    println("""
        result
        {${fromMapDefault} ${fromMapDefault?.javaClass}--> 1}
        {${fromMapDefault["7"]} ${fromMapDefault["7"]?.javaClass}--> 1}
        {${fromMapDefault["7"]?.get(0)}  ${fromMapDefault["7"]?.get(0)?.javaClass} --> 2}
        {${fromMapDefault["7"]?.get(0)?.id} ${fromMapDefault["7"]?.get(0)?.id?.javaClass}--> 3}
    """.trimIndent())

}


}

private fun printResult(fromMapDefault: Map<String, List<Model>>) {
    println("""
        result
        {${fromMapDefault} ${fromMapDefault?.javaClass}--> 1}
        {${fromMapDefault["7"]} ${fromMapDefault["7"]?.javaClass}--> 1}
        {${fromMapDefault["7"]?.get(0)}  ${fromMapDefault["7"]?.get(0)?.javaClass} --> 2}
        {${fromMapDefault["7"]?.get(0)?.id} ${fromMapDefault["7"]?.get(0)?.id?.javaClass}--> 3}
    """.trimIndent())

}
```

i change to yours model ClassStatus

```
data class ClassStatus(val status: Int, val error_message: String?, val data: Map<String,Map<String, ArrayList<Model>>>)
data class Model(val id: Long, val person_id: Long, val friend_id: Long)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val fromJson = Gson().fromJson<ClassStatus>(jj, ClassStatus::class.java)
    printResult(fromJson)
    //result
    //ClassStatus(status=0, error_message=null, data={1={7=[Model(id=1, person_id=3, friend_id=2)]}}) class pl.jac.gson2.not.ClassStatus--> 1
    //{1={7=[Model(id=1, person_id=3, friend_id=2)]}} class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap--> 2
    //{7=[Model(id=1, person_id=3, friend_id=2)]} class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap--> 3
    //[Model(id=1, person_id=3, friend_id=2)] class java.util.ArrayList--> 4
    //Model(id=1, person_id=3, friend_id=2) class pl.jac.gson2.not.Model--> 5
    //1 long--> 6
}

private fun printResult(fromMapDefault: ClassStatus) {
    println("""
            result
            ${fromMapDefault} ${fromMapDefault.javaClass}--> 1
            ${fromMapDefault.data} ${fromMapDefault.data.javaClass}--> 2
            ${fromMapDefault.data["1"]} ${fromMapDefault.data["1"]?.javaClass}--> 3
            ${fromMapDefault.data["1"]!!["7"]} ${fromMapDefault.data["1"]!!["7"]!!.javaClass}--> 4
            ${fromMapDefault.data["1"]?.get("7")!![0]} ${fromMapDefault.data["1"]!!["7"]!![0].javaClass}--> 5
            ${fromMapDefault.data["1"]?.get("7")!![0].id} ${fromMapDefault.data["1"]!!["7"]!![0].id!!.javaClass}--> 6
        """.trimIndent())
}

val jj = "{\n" +
        "\"status\": 0,\n" +
        "\"error_message\": null,\n" +
        "\"data\": {\n" +
        "\"1\": {\n" +
        "  \"7\": [\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
        "      \"person_id\": \"3\",\n" +
        "      \"friend_id\": \"2\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  ]\n" +
        " }\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "}"
```